# AJAX based remote Online text editor

Tags: python, ide, text-editor

I'm looking to install an online text editor on my server, that I can link to svn.

I would like to have some form of syntax highlighting, keyboard shortcuts, and perhaps some text complete.

Languages, python, php, sql, and C++ are a minimum ...

any suggestions?

Comment: I do not have an answer for you, but it reminds me of an idea I had, and it amuses me so.

Comment: I started working on a Flash-based one... but it's sitting on my website unfinished. If there is sufficient interest, I might resurrect it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any browser-based client-server editors like that, assuming I understand correctly what you are trying to do.

Two things come to mind:

1. Since it's a long-solved problem
   and generally fairly trivial task to
   configure a `svn` server
   and there are plenty of
   text editors / IDEs out there with
   `svn` client interfaces, why re-invent
   the wheel?
2. If you must or really want to
   and have gobs of time, go wild and
   crazy perhaps by starting with a
   simple existing Python-based editor
   ([Leo](http://webpages.charter.net/edreamleo/front.html) perhaps?) or roll you own
   and/or existing syntax highlighting
   packages, like [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), find a way to split it into a client-server
   architecture with some AJAX glue between them, and
   port the front-end client part to run under
   [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/), a framework for
   running a subset of Python as
   JavaScript, and to use a browser as the GUI.  And let us know how it
   turns out!

Answer (score 2):

you should have a look at https://mozillalabs.com/bespin/

I've tried it and decided not to use it, but only because it's web-based, the same reason why I use googledocs only when I really need to.

If you don't want to build a public service, you may use the approach I like. That is to install your favourite editor/IDE at the server and start ssh server. From the client, connect with enabled X forwarding (to connect from Windows, use Xming an portablePuTTY).